# validation on JSP page does not work

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, validation, servlets

I have the following jsp page with one input textbox, upon entering the number, the page is redirected to a servlet where I retrieve that number and let's say display it on a page. I'm trying to do the validation in JavaScript but in spite of it, it's still executing the servlet even though validation returns false and I get `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` in the `doGet` method on the servlet on the following line: `int max = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("lengthTxt"));`. Why does it seem to bypass validation and still execute the servlet ? How to fix it ? thanks for help !

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
    if(document.frm.lengthTxt.value=="")
    {
      alert("Number should not be left blank");
      document.frm.lengthTxt.focus();
      return false;
    }

}
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Length calc</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>enter length</h3>
<form name=frm action="MyServlet" onSubmit="return validateForm();">

    <input name="lengthTxt" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a Javascript problem, not Java (JSP, Servlet, etc..). Try to use Chrome DevTool to debug the javascript

Comment: Where is document.frm.username field??

Comment: @Vedang Shrimankar my spelling mistake, should be  lengthTxt

Comment: Now check it works or not??

Comment: What error you get same?? redirect to server side?

Comment: yes the same error, same thing

Comment: At my side it works fine.. write in a servlet Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("lengthTxt").toString());

Comment: This works for me on firefox. the form is not submitted if the form field is empty)

Comment: This is working for me too. Check in the console the value of the input and that the select is finding it. By that I mean enter "document.frm.lengthTxt.value" and see what it brings.

Comment: for me it still goes to the servlet and displays HTTP 500 Internal server error

Comment: the is an alert message displayed with "Number should not be left blank" but as soon as I click OK it goes to the servlet !

Comment: if you given wrong name in field to focus then it happens otherwise it should be work fine. From my side it works please check again in js function.

Comment: I got it now, thank you @Vedang Shrimankar

Comment: Pro Tip:  There is a path through your function that returns `undefined`.  Always debug your function to make sure it flows all the way through from beginning to end, and always returns a value.

Comment: Hi Frugo this is still open a question. I have posted in a answer so that it marked as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you given wrong name in field to focus then it happens otherwise it should be work fine.  please check again in java Script function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems insane.After checking this code on some browsers.It will execute form submit event even the the onsubmit returned with a false value like this.

```
onsubmit="return validateForm()";
```

So that you can prevent further form exection with `event.preventDefault()` function.

So that using Conditional Statement in `onsubmit` will save the day.Below goes the full statement to be used.

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return validateMyForm();">
```

Anything more,jz comment.